# Implement a whitespace golfer

Tags: code-golf, number, whitespace

Some two-dimensional esolangs, such as [Forked](//git.io/Forked), and some non-esolangs, such as [Python](//python.org), can sometimes require spaces before lines of code. This isn't very golfy. <sub><sup>Also, I'm lazy and writing a 2d lang that needs lots of spaces before code.</sup></sub> Your task is to write a tool that makes these languages golfier.

Of course, this will not be perfect; it cannot be used, for instance, when a number is the first character on a line of source. However, it will generally be useful.

## Challenge

You will write a program or function that either...

- ...takes one argument, a filename or a string, or...
- ...reads from standard input.

Your program will act like [`cat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29), except:

- If the first character on any line is a number, your code will print *x* spaces, where *x* is that number.
- Otherwise, it will simply be printed.
- As will every other character in the input.

## Test cases

Input:

```
foo bar foo bar
1foo bar foo bar foo bar
2foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar
```

Output:

```
foo bar foo bar
 foo bar foo bar foo bar
  foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar
```

---

Input:

```
--------v
8|
8|
80
8,
7&
```

Output:

```
--------v
        |
        |
        0
        ,
       &
```

---

Input:

```
foo bar
bar foo
foo bar
```

Output:

```
foo bar
bar foo
foo bar
```

---

Input:

```
0123456789
1234567890
2345678901
3456789012
4567890123
```

Output:

```
123456789
 234567890
  345678901
   456789012
    567890123
```

## Rules

- Output must be exactly as input, except for lines where the first character is a number.
- Your program cannot append/prepend anything to the file, except one trailing newline if you desire.
- Your program may make no assumptions about the input. It may contain empty lines, no numbers, Unicode characters, whatever.
- If a number with more than one digit starts a line (e.g. `523abcdefg`), only the first digit (in the example, 5) should turn into spaces.

## Winner

Shortest code in each language wins. Have fun and good luck!

Comment: [Sandboxed post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13580/61563)

Comment: `Of course, this will not be perfect; it cannot be used, for instance, when a number is the first character on a line of source.` Not true, just make the first character a 0 (ahem, your last test case)

Comment: Can we read a list of strings from stdin ([is this valid](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/zKDy0JqUzCPth3fV6vz/H61UnJmXnpOqkJyRWGSvpKNUAcXOGanJ2XpAhldpcYlCVWpRPkjWAIrhsq65BSWVCjmZeakgaQiCSsYCAA))?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 9 bytes

```
m`^\d
$*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/NyEuJoVLRUvh//@0/HyFpMQiBSjNZYgmAJcwwiEBV8ClCwVlXBY1YGTAZaHDZa7GxQVTAlUO53MZGBoZm5iamVtYcsFZBlxwliEXnGXEBWcZAwA) Note: Trailing space on last line.

Answer (score 11):

## [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically), <s>69</s> 66 bytes

```
RBR3B~(+50<7?6{+54>7?6{-002+7~?6{(@5*1-1/1)6}}}(-6>7?6&@7+70-4~)6)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pck7CoAwEADRPgeRxBDczWdXQVQ8gjdQK8HWQiS5etQm1TyY/dqOfT3PO@dlXtycpA7Q80iPDn74awCs5vRJTqFGgw0qijFKQ/@vJtYMxidFKmdA63wgbjtRBKIIRZEVRe4F)

### Explanation:

First we do this initialization:

```
RBR3B
```

To set up this cube:

```
   533
   004
   000
411223455441
311222331440
311222331440
   555
   555
   200
```

The most important thing about this cube is that face `5` sums to 32, which is the value required to print spaces. Coincidentally, it also happens to be fairly short for all other computation. After that is done:

```
~( . . . )                                    Takes the first input, then loops indefinitely

  +50<7?6{+54>7?6{-002+7~?6{(@5*1-1/1)6}}}    Handle leading digit:
  +50<7?6{                               }    If input is greater than 47 ('0' is 48)
          +54>7?6{                      }     And input is less than 58 ('9' is 57)
                                              Then input is a digit
                  -002+7                      Set notepad equal to value of input digit
                        ~                     Take next input (only convenient place for it)
                         ?6{           }      If the notepad isn't 0
                            (        )6       While the notepad isn't 0:
                             @5                 Print a space
                               *1-1/1           Decrement the notepad by one
                                              Leading digit handled

     (-6>7?6&@7+70-4~)6                       Handle rest of line:
     (               )6                       While the notepad isn't 0:
      -6>7?6&                                   Exit if End of Input
             @7                                 Print the next character
               +70-4                            Set notepad to 0 if it was a newline
                    ~                           Take the next character
```

Comment: Wow, that's a good use of nested ... everything. +1

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @Zgarb

```
mΓo+?oR' i;±¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fc5Hxt@/wgdYVM60MbD237//@/Ulp@vkJSYpEClOYyRBOASxjhkIAr4NKFgjIuixowMuCy0OEyV@PigimBKofzuQwMjYxNTM3MLSy54CwDLjjLkAvOMuKCs4y5lAA)

Uses the same technique as @Jonathan Allan

#### Explanation

```
             ¶  -- split input into a list of lines
m               -- apply the following function to each line
 Γ              --   deconstruct the string into a head and a tail
  o+            --   prepend to the tail of the string ...
    ?      ±    --     if the head is a digit (n)
     oR' i      --       the string of n spaces
                --     else
          ;     --       the head of the string
                -- implicitly print list of strings line-by-line
```

Comment: [13 bytes](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fc5Hxt@/wgdYVM60MbD237//@/Ulp@vkJSYpEClOYyRBOASxjhkIAr4NKFgjIuixowMuCy0OEyV@PigimBKofzuQwMjYxNTM3MLSy54CwDLjjLkAvOMuKCs4y5lAA) with the use of `Γ`.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES8), <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
a=>a.replace(/^\d/gm,a=>''.padEnd(a))
```

<s>I don't think it can be improved much more.</s>
*Saved 1 byte thanks to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)* - Use ES8 features.

Comment: "*I don't think it can be improved much more.*" - You could save a byte by using ES8's `padEnd` like so: `s=>s.replace(/^\d/gm,m=>"".padEnd(m))`

Comment: @Shaggy. I didn't know ES8 is allowed already. Thanks.

Comment: If there's any single interpreter (i.e.,browser) out there that supports a feature then that feature is fair game here :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>24</s> 21+1 = <s>25</s> 22 bytes

Uses the `-p` flag. -3 bytes from GB.

```ruby
sub(/^\d/){"%#$&s"%p}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v7g0SUM/LiZFX7NaSVVZRa1YSbWg9v9/XSgo47KoASMDLgsdLnM1rrT8fIWkxCIuIFYAsmH8f/kFJZn5ecX/dQsA)

Comment: {"%#$&s"%""} saves 1 byte

Comment: And another byte if you use sub instead of gsub

Comment: @GB and another byte by putting `%p` at the end instead of `%""`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>98</s> <s>74</s> <s>67</s> 65 bytes

*-24 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan. -7 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder.*

```python
for i in open('f'):print' '*int(i[0])+i[1:]if'/'<i[:1]<':'else i,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc09DsMgDAXg3aewWBzatAXSX5SeJGLoAIqliqAEKe3pabow@Rvee07fPE7RlOw/GZ8ohAClTXe@XG/3B1QpqNJQZaCqg606aHvQDmDlPOKUfGwoUIu0ksTXgsFiOK4zZ9/838kSphkZOdastGnmmAlpt52GB@XknrdZx4FO1PNgtevJkn8vHrkt5Qc)

Takes input in the file named `f`.

Comment: Also errors when no digit in the first character of a line (when using a list as a way to choose items all the elements are evaluated)

Comment: [back to 89](https://tio.run/##PY5BDoIwEEX3c4oJm7YaCQUVJSEeBLrAIDqKbUObGE9fi4vu3s/MvD/26x9Gl2Fq@zAP7@s4oGtYr1n@NKQ5p66RKic30p08F4MeGbINaR8nhRJmwf@G2FInGzWtGUmjy52d48FqEiL4m/PYYpZlUMiy2h@O9ekMiQpIJCFRCYkqgBo@Znm5C0RJrNpJBWCX@AhOfNWL8AM)

Comment: [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY3RCoIwFIbvz1Ps7rgScVpZg@hBzIvFtA7p2ZhC9PRLCXb3wffz/f67vBxX0fmer6OZHtYINlOfi8nZXiNiqar6cDw15wskKiGRgkQVJKoBGvi48J5vayIOLggSxGK7yXDAHAPKYvYjLRneGaX2gXjJqNWqK2i29FyNNGxR4O5vyk5umW0h99Qq3cX4Aw) - TIO link's header is mocking `open`; code is expecting a file named 'f'. I think it's OK?

Comment: Ah, true the `' '*0` is falsey. Using `[:1]` is still a save though. No need for `read` I believe (and it would be `readlines`) since the default behaviour of `open` is to iterate through the lines. Also there is no need for the mode since `'r'` is the default. If I'm right that's [73](https://tio.run/##PY3BDoIwEETv@xV7W6qGUFDRJsQPQQ4Yim6EtmlJjF9fISY9zctMZsZ9l5c1ZbROm2bq58fQo@lnfcDZDrohT4qICllWx9O5vlwhUQGJJCQqIVEFUMPH@ne4rRN5cBMvGd0NiThaj4xscLvNaCShnGezxki7TbktOsEjcqtkl3MY@LmWhZ6C/ntiz61UXYw/) !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63470/discussion-between-jonathan-allan-and-totallyhuman).

Comment: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##PY3NDsIgEITv@xSbvQBatbT@kvokDQcPkG5iaNOSoE@PrQdO800yk2/6xmEMTY7uE/GJRAS1btrz5Xq7P6BQDYU0FGqgUAvrtdfmoC1A4jjgOLkghRcViiQUvhb0Bv0xzRyd3HQq@3FGRg5lq8w0c4hSoNhtyX1tFXs6Uce90bYjQ@69OPw3tefVaKucfw). `isdigit()` can be replaced by lexicographical comparison, which saves tons of bytes

Comment: 67 bytes: `for i in open('f'):print(' '*int(i[0])+i[1:]if"/"<i[:1]<":"else i),`. It is better to add the whole string at once, saves 4 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
v0y¬dićú},
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/zKDy0JqUzCPth3fV6vz/H61UnJmXnpOqkJyRWGSvpKNUAcXOGanJ2XpAhldpcYlCVWpRPkjWAIrhsq65BSWVCjmZeakgaQiCSsYCAA)

Comment: How does one input with empty lines?

Comment: No idea lol... I'll look into it

Comment: [`|vy¬dićú},`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/pqzy0JqUzCPth3fV6vz/b2BoZGxiamZuYckFZxlwwVmGXHCWERecZQwA) works for 10 bytes.

Comment: OK, it's not one cannot input an empty line, it's that the code [does not work for an empty line](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/pqzySLtLSubhDYen19rr/P9fnJmXnpOqkJyRWGTPVQGEzhmpydl6XF6lxSUKValF@fZcBkAIFXXNLSipVMjJzEu15@KCCgIA): if one uses a single zero it works, so it must be something about the head not existing (same goes for @Riley's suggested 10 byter by the way).

Comment: @JonathanAllan It has something to do with the way `|` works. It is supposed to `push the rest of input as an array with strings`, but it stops at empty lines ([TIO](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/5v//4sy89JxUheSMxCJ7rgogdM5ITc7W4/IqLS5RqEotyrfnMgBCqKhrbkFJpUJOZl6qPRcXVBAA)). I brought this up in the [05AB1E chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33375/05ab1e-oasis) if you want to know more.

Comment: I've confirmed that `|` does not allow empty lines, since that is the signal to end fetching [see this line of code](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/osabie.py#L733).

Comment: Furthermore [`EvyćDdið×}?,`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/ftazySLtLSubhDYen19rr/P8frWRgaGSspKNkZGRsAqSMjU1MgRQQJWekJmcrxQIA) or [`Evy¬dićú},`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/ftazy0JqUzCPth3fV6vz/H61kYGhkrKSjZGRkbAKkjI1NTIEUECVnpCZnK8UCAA) still dont work because the empty string has no head, so would need replacing with zero prior to the rest of the processing.

Comment: Using @Riley's 10 byter and modifying to accept a single input as a list of strings works for 12 bytes as [`Ev0yë¬dićú},`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/ftcyg8vDqQ2tSMo@0H95Vq/P/f7RSWn6@QlJikQKUVtJRMkQTQpIywiGFpASIdKGgDMi2qIETBiBCB0iYq0HUITRBjUARAyIDQyNjE1MzcwtLkLNgbJA5cLYhkANnGwE5cLaxUiwA) though.

Comment: @JonathanAllan [`v0y¬dićú},`](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/zKDy0JqUzCPth3fV6vz/H61UnJmXnpOqkJyRWGSvpKNUAcXOGanJ2XpAhldpcYlCVWpRPkjWAIrhsq65BSWVCjmZeakgaQiCSsYCAA) should work. And we're back to 10 bytes :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 95 bytes

```python
lambda y:'\n'.join(re.sub('^\d',lambda x:' '*int(x.group()),z)for z in y.split('\n'))
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCoMwEEX3OcWsOpmShkIXFcGbhIKibVM0iWMsRnr3tBYff/f4L6T49O6Sx8rkvh6atoZUonGoX946yZ2e5kbizbSodr@UCHi0LspFP9jPQRKple6eYQXrIOkp9DbKrUIk7BA8R@AuB95Oo0REcdp5i@Lz31kUSlwP4ieJ8hc)

-4 bytes by stealing the regex idea from ThePirateBay

Comment: You *stole from ThePirateBay*, how the tables have turned

Comment: @Moonstroke HAH lol I didn't even notice that :P

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
V⁶ẋ
ḢÇ¹e?ØD;
ỴÇ€Yḟ0
```

A monadic link taking and returning lists of characters, or a full program printing the result.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/sUeO2h7u6uR7uWHS4/dDOVPvDM1ysuR7u3nK4/VHTmsiHO@Yb/P//X11dPS0/XyEpsUgBSnMZognAJYxwSMAVcOlCQRmXRQ0YGXBZ6HCZq3FxwZRAlcP5XAaGRsYmpmbmFpZccJYBF5xlyAVnGXHBWcZAZwMA)**

#### How?

```
V⁶ẋ - Link 1, make spaces: character (a digit)
V   - evaluate as Jelly code (get the number the character represents)
 ⁶  - a space character
  ẋ - repeat

ḢÇ¹e?ØD; - Link 2, process a line: list of characters
Ḣ        - head (get the first character and modify the line)
         -   Note: yields zero for empty lines
     ØD  - digit characters = "0123456789"
    ?    - if:
   e     - ...condition: exists in? (is the head a digit?)
 Ç       - ...then: call the last link as a monad (with the head as an argument)
  ¹      - ...else: identity (do nothing; yields the head)
       ; - concatenate with the beheaded line

ỴÇ€Yḟ0 - Main link: list of characters
Ỵ      - split at newlines
 Ç€    - call the last link (1) as a monad for €ach
   Y   - join with newlines
    ḟ0 - filter out any zeros (the results of empty lines)
```

Comment: `beheaded line` Is that the actual term? xD

Comment: Well, it is now :)

Comment: Ahahaha I tried outgolfing you and ended up with a solution essentially identical to yours xD

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 13 + 1 (-p) = 14 bytes

```perl
s/^\d/$"x$&/e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YPy4mRV9FqUJFTT/1//@0/CIuw6TEIi6jpMQqrqScxAwu4/KMzCoQ/19@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQ4P/ugUA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>76 72</s> 68 bytes

*-4 bytes thanks to [@ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)*!

@DeadPossum suggested switching to Python 2, which saved 4 bytes too.

Just thought it's nice to have a competitive full program in Python 2 that does not *explicitly* check if the first character is a digit. This reads the input from a file, `f`.

```python
for i in open('f'):
 try:r=int(i[0])*" "+i[1:]
 except:r=i
 print r,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzLCsIwEEX38xVDFibRKNWNJdAvKV2IJHY2SUgHY8F/j/GBl7s7h5NWnmM41YUzhdsghNj/dof@@XkHvYHzpiGAQjxjTC4o6aWRRWq8LOgtIPpDycROfUsaqo8ZCSn8fd00zqvNAwVWNHaT3goUOxqPdgJ0j6tL/KaAqTUYs6n1BQ) (courtesy of [@ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs))

Comment: @ovs Thanks for that

Comment: @ovs What did you change (I will do it by hand) ? It tells me that the permalink cannot be decoded

Comment: Instead of printing in every iteration I assigned the output to a variable and printed it all at the end.

Comment: @ovs I managed to get 72 bytes by printing every iteration, thanks for the variable idea!

Comment: Python 2 version of `print` will give you [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##PYzLCsIwEEX38xVDFibRKNWNJdAvKV2IJHY2SUgHY8F/j/GBl7s7h5NWnmM41YUzhdsghNj/dof@@XkHvYHzpiGAQjxjTC4o6aWRRWq8LOgtIPpDycROfUsaqo8ZCSn8fd00zqvNAwVWNHaT3goUOxqPdgJ0j6tL/KaAqTUYs6n1BQ)

Comment: @DeadPossum Yeah, I know. Perhaps I'll switch to 2

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 63 bytes

```hs
unlines.map g.lines
g(x:r)|x<';',x>'/'=(' '<$['1'..x])++r
g s=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYrbCoJAEIbv5ykGlFbxkIdKK@2mF/C@utjCNmldw0MI2bNvILYXQcPAfP/8340295xz@XI05FSwjrIc91mGmvOGkhYCUyxEm9f00qKOR9kJXoi8cUv6QOaODMzoN7U59AnZErvfkTlJDYIk0Q/EJ67bn0zLqoFhkzZSXqsKz7TG6YL/81BF8KdQAjjTPCEexvUgtiGaAXyVSVcZPD8IF8tVFK9BkQeKfFAUgKLwAw) The first line is an anonymous function which splits a given string into lines, applies the function `g` to each line and joins the resulting lines with newlines. In `g` it is checked whether the first character `x` of a line is a digit. If this is the case, then `['1'..x]` yields a string with length equal to the value of the digit `x` and `' '<$` converts the string into as many spaces. Finally the rest of the line `r` is appended. If `x` is not a digit we are in the second equation `g s=s` and return the line unmodified.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/), <strike>105</strike> <strike>99</strike> <strike>97</strike> 93 bytes

*Saved few more bytes thanks to Nevay's suggestion,*

```
s->{int i=s.charAt(0);if(i>47&i<58)s=s.substring(1);while(i-->48)s=" "+s;System.out.print(s);}
```

Comment: You have two bugs in your golfed version: The digit check has to use and instead of or; The brackets after the digit check are missing. Besides that you can save a few bytes by using `s->{int i=s.charAt(0);if(i>47&i<58)for(s=s.substring(1);i-->48;s=" "+s);System.out.print(s);}` (93 bytes).

Comment: @Nevay You are right. Thanks. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/) (v2.0a0), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

Japt beating Jelly *and* 05AB1E? That doesn't seem right!

```
r/^\d/m_°ç
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=ci9eXGQvbV+w5w==&input=IjAxMjM0NTY3ODkKMTIzNDU2Nzg5MAoyMzQ1Njc4OTAxCjM0NTY3ODkwMTIKNDU2Nzg5MDEyMyI=)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of string `U`

```
r/^\d/m
```

Use Regex replace (`r`) all occurrences of a digit at the beginning of a line (`m` is the multiline flag - the `g` flag is enabled by default in Japt).

```
_
```

Pass each match through a function, where `Z` is the current element.

```
°
```

The postfix increment operator (`++`). This converts `Z` to an integer without increasing it for the following  operation.

```
ç
```

Repeat a space character `Z` times.

Implicitly output the resulting string.

Comment: Can `m@` be shortened?

Comment: Not in this case, @Oliver; the `m` here is the multi-line flag for the regex, not the map method.

Comment: @Oliver: `r/^\d/m_î` (or `r/^\d/m_ç`) *would* be 2 bytes shorter but `Z` is a string so, unfortunately, it wouldn't work. `r/^\d/m_°ç`, for a 1 byte saving, *does* work, though :)

Comment: `°ç` is an amazing trick :-) I'd have suggested just `\d` for the regex, but that leaves out the flag... perhaps I should add support for flags on single-class regexes, like `\dm` (oh yeah, and that leaves out the `^` too...)

Comment: @ETHproductions, would it be feasible/possible to make the opening `/` optional in RegExes?

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>138</s> 128 bytes

*-9 bytes thanks to CriminallyVulgar*

```r
n=readLines();for(d in grep("^[0-9]",n))n[d]=gsub('^.?',paste0(rep(' ',eval(substr(n[d],1,1))),collapse=''),n[d]);cat(n,sep='
')
```

This is pretty bad, but it's a bit better now... R is, once again, terrible at strings.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcpBCoMwEEDRfU4R3MwMjMXYboqEXqA3EIVoogiShMT2@mmFdvfh/VSK18kZ@9y8y0jdEhJauXm5JhexGvumvg8VeyLf20Gv@TUhjJcHcDT5cA2eG0hg9zY7fjUfCc@VFSsi4jnsu4nZaQDiE6ibzYGes4saBFBR7fUmzDRbsYQgJ5OE@kf7i/IB)

Comment: I am commenting on behalf of [CriminallyVulgar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/72784/criminallyvulgar), who suggests a [129-byte](https://tio.run/##NcpBCoMwEEDRvacIbmYGpsXYboqEXqA3sArRRBFCEhLb66cV2t2H91MpXiWrzWPzNiN1S0hoxObFmmzEeuyb022o2RP53gxqza8JYTzfgaPOu23w2EAA27d2@NW8JzxWliyJiOfgnI7ZKgDiA6ib9Y6es40Knh6oyPZyrfQ0m2oJQUw6VfIf7S/KBw) version, but does not have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thank you and @CriminallyVulgar!

Comment: [123 Bytes](https://tio.run/##NYpBCoMwEADvviJ42V3YFmN7KRL6gf7AKkQTpSCbkNj3pxXa2zAzqRQxyVv3eInPSN0SEjr1ErUmH7Ee@@Z0G2oWIundYNb8nhDG8x042rz7Bo8NFPA35D3hcbFmTcRz2DYbszcAxIenbrY7CmcfDTwFqOj2cq3sNLtqCUFNNlX6D@0Pygc "R – Try It Online") Apparently rep can take a string of an int for the second argument???

Comment: @CriminallyVulgar huh. it's right there in the [docs for rep](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rep.html), now that I check them again: "other inputs being coerced to an integer or double vector".

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 19 bytes

```
Ḣ⁶ẋ;µ¹µḣ1ẇØDµ?
ỴÇ€Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AU0Asv9qZWxsef//4bii4oG24bqLO8K1wrnCteG4ozHhuofDmETCtT8K4bu0w4figqxZ////IjdIZWxsb1xuOVdvcmxkIVxuLS0tXG5cbmhpIg)

-5 bytes total thanks to Jonathan Allan's comments and by looking at his post

## Explanation

```
Ḣ⁶ẋ;µ¹µḣ1ẇØDµ?  Main link
             ?  Ternary if
                if:
       ḣ1       the first 1 element(s) (`Head` would modify the list which is not wanted)
         ẇ      is a sublist of (essentially "is an element of")
          ØD    "0123456789"
                then:
  ẋ             repeat
 ⁶              ' '
Ḣ               n times where n is the first character of the line (head)
   ;            concatenate the "beheaded" string (wording choice credited to Jonathan Allan)
                else:
     ¹          Identity (do nothing)
    µ µ     µ   Link separators
ỴÇ€Y            Executed Link
Ỵ               Split by newlines
  €             For each element,
 Ç              call the last link on it
   Y            Join by newlines
```

Comment: no need to swap arguments: `Ḣ⁶ẋ;`

Comment: The pop then head trick wont work if there is a line containing only a single digit character :(  -- `;0Ḣ` would work for one byte, maybe there is a single atom, I also tried `¹`, no joy there

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ah right. Thanks. `ḣ1ẇØD` works for the same bytecount \o/

Comment: `ṚṪ` will work :)

Comment: @JonathanAllan That works too :) But I made an explanation already for my method so I'm too lazy to change it :P But thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth),  <s>16</s>  15 bytes

```
jm.x+*;shdtdd.z
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/PytXr0Jby7o4I6UkJUWv6v9/XSgo47KoASMDLgsdLnM1AA)**

---

## Explanation

```
jm.x+*;shdtdd.z   - Full program that works by reading everything from STDIN.

             .z  - Read all STDIN and split it by linefeeds.
 m               - Map with a variable d.
  .x             - Try:
     *;shd           - To convert the first character to an Integer and multiply it by a space.
    +     td         - And add everything except for the first character
            d        - If the above fails, just add the whole String.
j                 - Join by newlines.
```

Let's take an example that should be easier to process. Say our input is:

```
foo bar foo bar
1foo bar foo bar foo bar
2foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar
```

The program above will do the following:

- `.z` - Reads it all and splits it by newlines, so we get `['foo bar foo bar', '1foo bar foo bar foo bar', '2foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar']`.
- We get the first character of each: `['f', '1', '2']`.
- If it is convertible to an integer, we repeat a space that integer times and add the rest of the String. Else, we just place the whole String. Hence, we have `['foo bar foo bar', ' foo bar foo bar foo bar', '  foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar']`.
- Finally, we join by newlines, so our result is:

  ```
  foo bar foo bar
   foo bar foo bar foo bar
    foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar
  ```

Comment: Haha, we beat Jelly :)

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 9 bytes

```
ç^ä/x@"é
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v///DyuMNL9CsclA6vVPj/38DQyNjE1MzcwpILzjLggrMMueAsIy44yxgA)

#### Explanation

```
ç  /      ' On lines matching
 ^ä       ' (Start)(digit)
    x     ' Delete the first character
     @"   ' (Copy Register) number of times
       é  ' Insert a space
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically), 82 bytes

```
R3D1R1D1+0(?6{?7@7~:1+2<7?6{+35>7?6{:7-120?6{(B3@5B1-0)6}:0}}}?6!@7~-60=7&6+4-3=7)
```

Note: This will not work on [TIO](https://tio.run/##PcsxCoQwEIXhPrewWZQQmMmYGQ2rEfEE3kCtFmwtRLJXz2abVO97xX9c@@fYzvNOaaUFV1xQQx34CTLJ16O2b8lPkxv/68WghYx6psnNaKDh6CHGGLjKgWEY5MW6NTRIkxKgpdaxdL0qAlWEqsiqIvoB). To test this, use the [Lua interpreter](https://github.com/Cubically/cubically-lua) with the experimental flag set to true (to enable conditionals). There's currently a bug with conditional blocks on the TIO interpreter. When using the TIO interpreter, you should replace `?6!` with `!6` and `&6` with `?6&`, which keeps the byte count the same.

```
R3D1R1D1          Set the cube so that face 0 has value 1 and the rest of the values are easy to calculate

+0                Set the notepad to 1 so that it enters the conditional below
(                 Do
  ?6{               If the notepad is 1 (last character was \n or start of input)
    ?7@7              Output the current character if it's \n
    ~                 Get the next character
    :1+2<7?6{         If the input is >= '0'
      +35>7?6{          If the input is <= '9'
        :7-120            Set the notepad to the input - '0'
        ?6{               If the notepad isn't 0
          (                 Do
            B3@5              Output a space
            B1-0              Subtract 1 from notepad
          )6                While notepad > 0
        }                 End if
        :0              Set notepad to 1
      }                 End if
    }                 End if
  }                 End if

  ?6!@7             If the notepad is 0 (did not attempt to print spaces), print current character

  ~                 Get next character
  -60=7&6           If there is no more input, exit the program
  +4-3=7            Check if current character is \n, setting notepad to result
)                 Repeat forever
```

This isn't as short as the other Cubically answer, but I thought I'd give this a try anyway :D

Comment: What's going on with loops in the TIO interpreter?

Comment: @MDXF `)` jumps to the most recent `(` rather than the matching one I believe. EDIT: I'm in the chat.

Comment: @MDXF Maybe it was the conditional blocks, actually. I forgot, I'll update the answer. Regardless, they weren't matching up.

Comment: All right, I'll look at that later. I'm currently finishing Cubically 2.

Comment: @MDXF That's... really exciting to hear actually o_O

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 60 bytes

```
!^i:0(?;::"/")$":"(*0$.
v"0"-
>:?!v1-" "o
;>:o>a=&10&?.i:0(?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/XzEu08pAw97aykpJX0lTRclKSUPLQEWPq0zJQEmXy87KXrHMUFdJQSmfy9rOKt8u0VbN0EDNXg@s6f9/XSgo47KoASMDLgsdLnM1AA)

#### How It Works:

```
..i:0(?;... Gets input and ends if it is EOF
...
...
...

.^......::"/")$":"(*0$. If the inputted character is a digit go to the second line
...                     Else go to the fourth
...
...

....        If it was a digit
v"0"-       Subtract the character "0" from it to turn it into the corresponding integer
>:?!v1-" "o And print that many spaces before rejoining the fourth line
...

.^..               On the fourth line,
....               Copy and print the input (skip this if it was a digit)
....v              If the input is a newline, go back to the first line.
;>:o>a=&10&?.i:0(? Else get the input, ending on EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

## Gema, 21 characters

```
\N<D1>=@repeat{$1;\ }
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ gema '\N<D1>=@repeat{$1;\ }' <<< 'foo bar foo bar
> 1foo bar foo bar foo bar
> 2foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar
> 
> --------v
> 8|
> 8|
> 80
> 8,
> 7&'
foo bar foo bar
 foo bar foo bar foo bar
  foo bar foo bar foo bar foo bar

--------v
        |
        |
        0
        ,
       &
```

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 83 chars

```
preg_replace_callback('/^\d/m',function($m){return str_repeat(' ',$m[0]);},$argv);
```

Comment: I think your code is not compliant with the input rules of this challenge, you should enclose this in a function with a `$s`  arg or populate it with the input. And it doesn't print anything

Comment: @LP154 is using `argv` acceptable?

Comment: @Petah If I'm correct in assuming `argv` is the command line args, then yes.